# setting audio session property to kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord why i m not able toplay both recording as well as ipod music simultaneously

Tags: iphone

i m setting session with kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord property but still i m not able to play both ipod music as well as recording????
how to do this ???is there is any way to do that...............

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound`.  Check out [the Audio Session guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).